# REST questions: advantages of REST over XML-RPC

Tags: rest, design-patterns

What is the advantage of using the REST verbs GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
instead of just using POST and embedding an XML-RPC operation description
in the POST body describing what we want to insert, update, or delete.
Plus, what if we wanted to do more than one of these operations in one
go, wouldn't the rest design be useless in this case, as REST does not
seem to support transactions or multiple operations in one go.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XML-RPC vs REST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710507/xml-rpc-vs-rest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are my thoughts on why i prefer REST services over others.

REST uses the HTTP verbs `GET, POST, PUT, DELETE` to convey the intention of the service.
A majority of the HTTP framework is used as is.

In my opinion, there is no need to circumvent the HTTP to build a new protocol. Only an understanding of HTTP is required to build and use RESTful services. I think a carefully designed service acting on any resource will fit into the RESTful model.

In a RESTful service, the operation on the resource is intuitive. So, when a GET operation is made on a resource, it is imperative that the operation is idempotent.
REST enables to use lighter payload. It so easy and light to make an ajax call to a RESTful service.

It provides the ability to service different request/response formats like json, xml etc by the same service.

Event though there is no ws transaction type support in REST, a RESTful service can be built to achieve the same consistent state.
There can be cases where REST is not appropriate, that depends on the architecture and the contract required for the solution.