# Cherrypy does not seem to work with curl post request

Tags: xml, curl, cherrypy

I have the curious problem where I have a `xmlrpc client` and `requests` work fine with the Cherrypy server. I however, noticed that the curl command does not work. I get:

```
raise cherrypy.HTTPError(404, message=message)
cherrypy._cperror.HTTPError: (404, 'Missing parameters: data')
```

My cherrypy function is simple:

```
class XML(cherrypy._cptools.XMLRPCController):

    @cherrypy.expose
    def POST(self, data):
        cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/xml'
        return data

#Option 1
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/xml'}
r = requests.post('http://localhost:8080/XML/POST', 
                  data=data,  
                  headers=headers,
                  stream=True)
#Option 2
xml_client = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('http://localhost:8080/XML/POST')
xml_client.POST(data)
```

The option that does not work is:

```
curl --form data=@data.xml -i -X POST 'http://localhost:8080/XML/POST/' -H 'Content-Type multipart/form-data' -H 'Accept application/soap+xml'
```

I would like to know why curl is not working with cherrypy the way the other two are working. I did try to find a reason but could not!
Any suggestions will be much appreciated!

**EDIT:**

Thanks to @cyraxjoe
For the answer, however as this is part of the solution, I want to make it easier to find. Found out that people suggest REST instead of XML-RPC for various of reasons, one could take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710507/xml-rpc-vs-rest). So I have removed the `XMLRPCController`
    class XML():

```
    @cherrypy.expose
    def POST(self):
        cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/xml'
        data = cherrypy.request.body.read()
        return data
```

Hopefully this will help someone else as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you have to put colons in the header `(-H`) options for curl.

```
curl --form data=@data.xml -i -X POST \
    -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
    -H 'Accept: application/soap+xml' 'http://localhost:8080/XML/POST/'
```

Without them, the `Accept` header is not configured. You can see what curl sends with the `-v` option.

Comment: You are correct! However, this is only half of the solution. The other bit is that the cherrypy function does not require parameter to be passed this way. 
`cherrypy.request.body.read()` , will read the data passed from curl.